# How do I pass an argument to the specflow runner?

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, arguments, cucumber, specflow

Mandatory disclaimer: I am new to specflow and c#. Thank you for your understanding.

I am currently converting a cucumber testing framework from java to c#.

My current setup is this. I have an environment file in which I have defined multiple environments (dev, qa, prod, etc...). each environment has a unique ID. What I used to do in my java framework, was to pass the ID of the environment I want to use through the Maven command-line call, and my framework would take care of the rest (read the ID using `System.getProperties("propertyName")`, find the file and read the variables if that specific ID). This would allow me to plug my testing framework in Jenkins and make different builds to run in different environments by just passing a different ID using the command-line.

Now I'm having a bit of trouble to find how to manage this with specflow. I mean, I have no trouble reading my file, what I'm still struggling with is how to pass to specflow the ID of the environment that I want to use so that I can pick it up from withing my framework. This is also considering that I plan to upload this to TFS so that I can have my tests launched from there (similar to what I did in Jenkins).

The objective here is to avoid having to manually swap in and out multiple environment files.

In the case that this is not possible, are there any good alternatives?

Thank you.

EDIT: Ok So some colleagues of mine suggested that I use the Test Settings. In my local solution, I can generate 1 file for each environment that I need. Then, I TFS, I can feed the build with overriding values, which will serve just fine.

So I created a `dev.runsettings` file and from what I gathered, I need to access it's content using the following:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

TestContext context = ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioContainer.Resolve<TestContext>();
```

I run this in a `[BeforeScenario]` method. However, it throws an exception.

```
Impossible to create an instance of Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestContext, because it is an abstract class
```

I've found this [thread](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/936) on specflow's github about this issue, and it seems that it's supposed to be resolved, but I'm still getting the error.

Any thoughts?

EDIT2: Ok So I ended up realizing that since I'm using Nunit 3, I don'T need to use the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` library, I can use the `Nunit.framework` library directly. which leads me to a new issue. My `TestContext.Parameters` does not get populated. I verified that my runsettings file is valid, and that it is selected and checked in VS 2017 Test menu. But the parameters are not read and made available in the TestContext. I've look around (I've been on this whole issue the whole day), and based on what I've found, it should work. And I have no idea why it doesn't.

Comment: Is TestContext now a MSTest class or a NUnit class?

Comment: It's an NUnit class, I'm starting to believe that my issue is that it's not properly initialized, or I'm not sure if it needs to be... the more I read about it, the more confused I get, because MSTest seems also to have a TestContext class and everytime I search on google, it seems to confuse the two and I can't seem to ge tthe right answer...